# Exporting Igraph Layout to Cytoscape

Tags: r, networking, igraph, cytoscape

I created an igraph plot in `R` using the data frame `Diff` and the adjacency matrix `adjacency` and would like to save the plot obtained via `layout.mds` in a format readable in `Cytoscape`. How can I possibly do that?

The data frames are as follow:

Diff:

```
 0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
 0.1  0.0  0.5  0.6  0.7
 0.2  0.5  0.0  0.8  0.9
 0.3  0.6  0.8  0.0  1.0
 0.4  0.7  0.9  1.0  0.0
```

adjacency:

```
0  1  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  1  0
0  1  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Here are the codes used to obtain the plot:

```
data <- Diff

library(igraph)
graph <- graph.full(nrow(data))

layout <- layout.mds(graph, dist=as.matrix(data), dim=3)
edge <- graph.adjacency(as.matrix(adjacency),mode="directed")

plot(edge, layout=layout)
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cytoscape-discuss/RyzCBVY9EAQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use our package [NetPathMiner](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/NetPathMiner.html) which has a function `plotCytoscapeGML` to export network plots to GML format, which can be imported directed in Cytoscape.

**Note:** It should also be doable using a RESTful solution [example here](http://rpubs.com/keiono/24510).

**Note:** `RCytoscape` suggested in the comments are not compatible with Cytoscape 3.